# Why is this a good question?

Tags: discussion

This question [Does there exist an internet-like peer-to-peer packet radio system?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24763/319) seems to have a good number of people interested in it, but I don't see how this is a good fit here.

It feels to me to be a surface level question that is interested in finding a consumer product. It just happens to be asked by someone who comes from an engineering background and understands some of the challenges of designing the product.

So what makes this questions a good fit here?

Comment: Note... I am not pushing to have this question closed, just wondering what made it a good question.

Answer (score 8):

It is a technically detailed protocol research question, or at least that is how it looks to me.

I feel you are going to have to have some entry level questions for others to find the site and this seems like an entry level protocol research question just as sometimes we have questions where someone asks a very long question about some feature they are stuck on implementing and then you have an answer along the lines of, "This is an SCR, here is how they do everything you need with one component"

Comment: I agree with Kortuk -- I interpreted "radio system" in this question as asking about abstract "radio system protocols" that perhaps the original poster could build hardware to receive (which seems on-topic for electronics design). But I can see how someone might interpret "radio system" as "off-the-shelf commercial radio hardware that I could plug into a PC" (which seems more like a shopping question and therefore off-topic).